# document.getElementById returns undefined value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the increment and decrement input type value. that value shows undefined in javascript. how to do .

```
echo '<td id="textone_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['fee']. '</td>'; 
 echo '<td id="texttwo_'.$row['id'].'"> 
 <input type="number" min="0" max="999" name="india"  
 onChange="sum('.$row['id'].');" class="txtbox" disabled="disabled" ></td>';
  echo '<td> <input type="text" value="0"
 id="result_'.$row['id'].'" name="result"></td>';
  Ajax
  ************
<script type="text/javascript">
 function sum(rowid) {

   var txtFirstNumberValue =  
    document.getElementById('textone_'+rowid).innerHTML;
   alert(txtFirstNumberValue );  
   var txtSecondNumberValue = 
     document.getElementById('texttwo_'+rowid).value;
   alert(currentVal);        
   var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * 
    parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
   alert(result);
   if (!isNaN(result)) {
       document.getElementById('result_'+rowid).value = result;
    }
  }
</script>
```

how to solve this issue?

Comment: what is currentVal?

Comment: missing id in your tag

Comment: id is="texttwo_'.$row['id'].'"

Comment: are the id of td and the input identical?

Comment: Where is something like `var rowid=....`

Comment: the question, in my opinion, is not clear

Comment: As others pointed out: `rowid` is not set in your javascript. Also `getElementById('texttwo_'+rowid).value` doesn't have a `value`, it's a `<td>`.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of wrongs in your code.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
echo '<td id="texttwo_' . $row['id'] . '"> 
  <input type="number" min="0" max="999" name="sets" class="txtbox" onchange="getValue(this);" ></td>';
?>
<script>
    function getValue(obj) {
        alert(obj.value);
    }
</script>
```

**The following are the reasons why your code did not work:**

1. You disabled the input box, which means the increment/decrement
   arrows will not work in the first place.
2. Your `onchange()` function doesn't make sense. What are you trying to sum?
3. You define `txtSecondNumberValue` but you called `currentVal`.

Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) for more javascript insights.

Comment: But the value of the td is not present, no?

Comment: echo '<td id="textone_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['fee']. '</td>'; 
  echo '<td id="texttwo_'.$row['id'].'"> 
  <input type="number" min="0" max="999" name="india"  
  onChange="sum('.$row['id'].');" class="txtbox" disabled="disabled" ></td>';
   echo '<td> <input type="text" value="0"
   id="result_'.$row['id'].'" name="result"></td>';

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 function sum(rowid) {

       var txtFirstNumberValue =  document.getElementById('textone_'+rowid).innerHTML;
       alert(txtFirstNumberValue );  
       var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('texttwo_'+rowid).value;
       alert(currentVal);        
       var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
       alert(result);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('result_'+rowid).value = result;
       }
   }
  </script>

Comment: full coding uploaded in my post

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript value `txtSecondNumberValue` is attempting to retrieve the value of your `td` tag, instead of the input field. Also, you are alerting a JavaScript variable that is not defined anywhere. The *rowid* that you are concatenating in your attempt to get the value of your element is also wrong. It's not a JavaScript variable or anything else that contains anything at all. If anything, it will act as a string concatenation and you will try to retrieve the value of the following: `texttwo_rowid`, which doesn't exist.

Try the following:

```
<?php
echo '
<td id="td_'.$row['id'].'"> 
  <input type="number" min="0" max="999" name="sets[]" onChange="sum('.$row['id'].');" id="texttwo_'.$row['id'].'" class="txtbox" disabled="disabled" />
</td>';
?>
<script>
var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('texttwo_'+<?php echo $row['id']; ?>).value;
alert(txtSecondNumberValue);
</script>
```